# why openpyxl creating worksheet with name"Sheet1"?

Tags: python, office365, openpyxl

`openpyxl` creates spreadsheet with name "Sheet1" by default 
even though I'm specifying that the sheet should be created with index 0.
I'm sure it's not a duplicate question.
Documentation says `openpyxl` supports 2010 MS Office version but I'm using office365 pro.
Could you provide any help or suggestions?

Please note that standalone code is working fine for me but when the same code is being integrated with other code I experience the problem described below. 
I have tried many things. Since I'm new to Python it looks like there's something I'm not aware of.
If I specify index 1 there are two worksheets created: one with name `Sheet` and the other one with name I'm providing. If I provide Index 0 there is only one Sheet with name `Sheet1` created.

The code below should create worksheet at index 0 with name `test`.

```
            for r in range(3, rowcount + 1):
                for c in range(1, columncount + 1):
                    final_path = first_part + str(r) + second_part + str(c) + third_part
                    table_data = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(final_path).text

                    fname = r"{}_{}.xlsx".format(str(i[1]), str(i[2]))
                    if (os.path.exists(fname)):
                        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(fname)
                        worksheet = workbook[fname]
                    else:
                        workbook = Workbook()
                        worksheet= workbook.create_sheet(fname,0)
                        #worksheet = workbook.active
                        #worksheet.title = fname
                    worksheet.cell(row=r,column=c).value = table_data
                    workbook.save(fname)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get that sheet and remove like this :

`sheet = wb1.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')`

`wb1.remove_sheet(sheet)`

Answer (score 11):

`openpyxl` creates a single sheet called "Sheet" when you first call the `Workbook()` function. It's just a kind of annoying quirk of the module.. The cleanest way I found to deal with it is to just rename that sheet instead of attempting to make a new one

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "My sheet name"
wb.save("Test.xlsx")
```

Will create an xlsx file with a single worksheet called "My sheet name".
When you call `create_sheet` with index 0, you just insert a new sheet before this original sheet.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "My sheet name"
ws2 = wb.create_sheet("Another Name", 0)
wb.save("Test.xlsx")
```

Will create an xlsx where the first sheet is called "Another name" and the second sheet is called "My sheet name". If you're dealing with one sheet workbooks it's easiest to just use `title`.

Comment: Seeing as you cannot have a workbook without at least one worksheet I reckon it's essential rather than a "quirk".

Comment: Sure you can.. `Workbook(write_only=True)`. Saving it without creating one will produce some horrible errors of course..

Comment: You cannot save a workbook without a worksheet in it.

Comment: Well if you make a write_only Workbook at `wb`, you can see that `wb.worksheets` is empty.. if you just call `wb.save` it will create a single sheet called `Sheet` so that it works.. But if you run `wb.create_sheet("My sheet")` it will create a single sheet with your name.. without the quirk of having a random sheet called "Sheet" before it even though you didn't even run `wb.active`. That's the behavior the op expected because it makes sense (in my opinion).

Comment: In other words: your previous comment isn't correct. If you create a new workbook in Excel or other application you also get a "random sheet".

Answer (score 4):

You can remove this sheet via:

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook

workbook = Workbook()
del workbook['Sheet']
```